# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, yii2, foreach

В чем, может быть, причина появления ошибки ?

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Я понимаю, что аргумент не поддерживается функцией, но как это исправить ? Не взирая на ошибку, модели создаются, картинки сохраняются в папку, а пути записываются в базу.
Вот контроллер:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Vote();
    $model1 = new Images();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        $model1->image = UploadedFile::getInstances($model1, 'image');
        $a = $this->uniqueId;
        foreach ($model1->image as $image) {
            $image->saveAs($model1->rus2translit('upload/files/' . $a . '_' . $image->baseName . '.' . $image->extension));
            $ipath = $model1->rus2translit($a . '_' . $image->baseName . '.' . $image->extension);
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO images (v_id, imagepath) VALUES ('" . $model->id . "', '" . $ipath . "')")->execute();
        }
        $model1->save(false);
        return $this->redirect($url = Url::previous());
    }
    //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model, 'model1' => $model1,
    ]);
}
```

Вот модель отвечающая за изображения:

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/*
 * This is the model class for table "images".
 *
 * @property integer $v_id
 * @property string $imagepath
 * @property Vote[] $images
 */
class Images extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public $image=[];

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'images';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['v_id'], 'integer'],
        [['imagepath'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'jpg, jpeg, png, gif', 'maxFiles' => 6],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'v_id' => 'V ID',
        'imagepath' => 'Imagepath',
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * @return \common\models\query\ImagesQuery the active query used by this AR class.
 */
public static function find()
{
    return new \common\models\query\ImagesQuery(get_called_class());
}

public function rus2translit($string)
{
    $converter = array(
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v',
        'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e',
        'ё' => 'e', 'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z',
        'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k',
        'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r',
        'с' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u',
        'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c',
        'ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch',
        'ь' => '\'', 'ы' => 'y', 'ъ' => '\'',
        'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya',
        'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V',
        'Г' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E',
        'Ё' => 'E', 'Ж' => 'Zh', 'З' => 'Z',
        'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'Y', 'К' => 'K',
        'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N',
        'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R',
        'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U',
        'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C',
        'Ч' => 'Ch', 'Ш' => 'Sh', 'Щ' => 'Sch',
        'Ь' => '\'', 'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ъ' => '\'',
        'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'Yu', 'Я' => 'Ya',
        '—' => '-',
    );
    $string = strtr($string, $converter);
    return $string;
}

public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Vote::className(), ['vote_id' => 'id']);
}
}
```

На странице с ошибками указано следующее:

> in C:\OpenServer\domains\poll.ua\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\mysql\QueryBuilder.php

```
if (empty($names) && $tableSchema !== null) {
$columns = !empty($tableSchema->primaryKey) ? $tableSchema->primaryKey : reset($tableSchema->columns)->name;
foreach ($columns as $name) {
    $names[] = $schema->quoteColumnName($name);
    $placeholders[] = 'DEFAULT';
    }
}
```

тут на foreach ругается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$columns = !empty($tableSchema->primaryKey) ? $tableSchema->primaryKey : reset($tableSchema->columns)->name;
```

Насколько я понимаю, в переменной $columns будет либо primaryKey (если он не пустой), либо имя первой колонки.

Далее эта переменная (в которой хранится имя колонки), кладётся в foreach. Аргументом форича должен быть массив, а у вас в ней строка.

Соответственно надо или добавить

```
$columns = [$columns];
```

или убрать foreach.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Добавил еще одно поле Id и установил ему первичный ключ. Ошибка пропала. Но в бд теперь пишутся пути к картинкам и +1 поле с пустыми значениями, но заполненным id (так-как автоинкремент). Хотя у меня есть еще одна таблица, с почти аналогичными функциями. Там два поля в которые пишутся айди юзера и голосования. Дак вот там у меня нет первичного ключа, но foreach ни на что не ругается.
http://joxi.ru/5mdonRvcOVDLr1

Comment: Дело было в этой строчке `$model1->save(false);` она не нужна, вообще. Удалил ее и все работает как задумывалось. Без дополнительных полей в таблице. Магия :)